# Hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I want to try out the HBase-0.94 standalone mode and has followed the instruction in [Quick Start](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html).

I start hbase with `start-hbase.sh` and launch `hbase shell`

It seems that my master can't be initialized because my create table command always fails as following:

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 't1', 'cf'

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException:    
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing
```

Here's my `conf/hbase-site.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>/home/manuzhang/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/manuzhang/zookeeper</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

and my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1       jmx_host
127.0.1.1   manuzhang-U24E

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

74.125.237.1 dl-ssl.google.com
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: @CharlesMenguy add my hosts file

Comment: Not 100% sure, but can you try replacing the jmx_host by your hostname (seems to be manuzhang-U24E), restarting hbase and see if you have any progress?

Comment: @CharlesMenguy that's it. I see what the quick start guide means now

Comment: What if the HBase is supposed to be running on HDFS? This configuration has to use a URL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to edit  your /etc/hosts file because HBase probably can't connect to localhost using 127.0.0.1

You should replace the line :

```
127.0.0.1       jmx_host
```

with

```
127.0.0.1   manuzhang-U24E
```

Restart HBase after that to and hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: Does not work for me. I tried this option. I am still getting PleaseHoldException. its terrible thing to get productive on HBase

Comment: Worked for me, changed 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks a lot ,changing 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1 worked for me

Answer (score 4):

The HBase and /etc/hosts relationship is actually a very popular mystery. Although changing the line 127.0.1.1 or 127.0.0.1 might work, the process is actually quite involved.

When HBase is setting an RPC server, it’ll listen on the IP of the interface
defined in "hbase.regionserver.dns.interface". (Well, not quite, actually, HBase will
find the IPs of this interface, will look up for its hostname, and the first hostname of
the first IP associated to this network interface will be used).

What if you didn’t provide anything? It’ll get you back your hostname, assuming that your
host name is associated to the most reasonable interface.

[Reference](http://blog.devving.com/why-does-hbase-care-about-etchosts/)(Beautiful post. I would strongly suggest to read it once).

Comment: Cannot find the post you linked

Answer (score 1):

Please change the address 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1 in the line

```
127.0.1.1  manuzhang-U24E
```

restart hbase and it should work. This happens since hbase is not able to find the master host.